# What can I do if a spam email claims I'm infected with Pegasus spyware?

Tags: email, security, virus, spyware, pegasus

I opened my Outlook app (Firefox PWA) on my Android phone.

I was confused because I was logged out -I have "remember me" activated, so I have to login once every few months.

Then, I opened the spam folder and there I read a mail sent 4 days ago from my own mail to myself.

Its title says "Delivery Status Notification (Failure).".

I will leave the entire mail text here:

> Hello pervert,
>
> I want to inform you about a very bad situation for you. However, you can benefit from it, if you will act wisely.
>
> Have you heard of Pegasus?
> This is a spyware program that installs on computers and smartphones and allows hackers to monitor the activity of device owners.
> It provides access to your webcam, messengers, emails, call records, etc. It works well on Android, iOS, and Windows.
> I guess, you already figured out where I'm getting at.
>
> It's been a few months since I installed it on all your devices because you were not quite choosy about what links to click on the internet.
> During this period, I've learned about all aspects of your private life, but one is of special significance to me.
> I've recorded many videos of you jerking off to highly controversial porn videos.
> Given that the "questionable" genre is almost always the same, I can conclude that you have sick perversion.
>
> I doubt you'd want your friends, family and co-workers to know about it. However, I can do it in a few clicks.
> Every number in your contact book will suddenly receive these videos - on WhatsApp, on Telegram, on Skype, on email - everywhere.
> It is going to be a tsunami that will sweep away everything in its path, and first of all, your former life.
> Don't think of yourself as an innocent victim. No one knows where your perversion might lead in the future, so consider this a kind of deserved punishment to stop you.
>
> Better late than never.
> I'm some kind of God who sees everything.
> However, don't panic. As we know, God is merciful and forgiving, and so do I.
> But my mercy is not free.
>
> Transfer $1370 USD to my bitcoin wallet: 19XcwtFgu2riNf7L5uhVah7YkWiMJST34k
>
> Once I receive confirmation of the transaction, I will permanently delete all videos compromising you, uninstall Pegasus from all of your devices, and disappear from your life. You can be sure - my benefit is only money.
>
> Otherwise, I wouldn't be writing to you, but destroy your life without a word in a second.
>
> I'll be notified when you open my email, and from that moment you have exactly 48 hours to send the money.
> If cryptocurrencies are uncharted waters for you, don't worry, it's very simple.
> Just google "crypto exchange" and then it will be no harder than buying some useless stuff on Amazon.
>
> I strongly warn you against the following:
> ) Do not reply to this email. I sent it from a temp email so I am untraceable.
> ) Do not contact the police. I have access to all your devices, and as soon as I find out you ran to the cops, videos will be published.
> ) Don't try to reset or destroy your devices.
>
> As I mentioned above: I'm monitoring all your activity, so you either agree to my terms or the videos are published.
>
> Also, don't forget that cryptocurrencies are anonymous, so it's impossible to identify me using the provided address.
> Good luck, my perverted friend. I hope this is the last time we hear from each other.
>
> And some friendly advice: from now on, don't be so careless about your online security.

I'm thinking about factory resetting my phone and PC, running antivirus, but I think that won't be enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It is not a joke, it is, however, a common scam.

#### The PC is not infected at all.

A website somewhere was hacked that contained your email and possibly pass (for that site).

Someone used that list of emailaddresses and passwords to send mails like the one you received.

It is a lie. Your PC is *not* infected. You can simply delete the email.

It is very profitable for a scammer in a poor country. Here are some BTC addresses they use:

```
1FECxHyNFvYjj7FVQtmD1GrMxoLEBFHDCV
19XcwtFgu2riNf7L5uhVah7YkWiMJST34k
1LJsS3xXPx6Qsp9W2Vt9io3wAn5NmCcqbp
1Pd7qACCUtM1zVXixbyxuJCXmDi4D1qMjn
19WDuugpByHmmWxPQRjT61Jpb6fcJfHrqt
1E3mVbLSLLUgdmrp8GV5RRu1Qz5FkWs4rJ
1FXXt4n3GnZKGJeK4LkHmZdKxwpgMwS67e
1Abx3eY5pHFE1aC4AJLdU91qhHS5rzqP4E
1JVMTup4zuS1JMGXAYYRgvyr2PUmNnY6g2
13BfNz9CsS9YHDs2UeDkH6m7rZDM4Xo81u
19TkRECkDFuXq6E9zS7TxueE2RmZndJR8U
12mwSFYDyCWta8uMNxq52mENdi3nkjQGa5
12iPLbH9BGsBkbJvoy2iULyLYiawxZreT4
1AMt6qukzLnSoT2eTv5Z9c2G24nQqNLUry
1AmP3aXEb7tv5M8gRGQfbAADBMmBPFhJNj
185kB82fakN7BCDpcS9tfzbDc8uytm5Wo
1GXQym1cfFhHBFbqqZGp2tTQkAfU9yBS1w
19gjxoZ2x8xzNC18FYtLxCL3FWRi15cP39
1ELed4R6FhJEL5pQQzP6PM9wFQbvHjuZng
1BqMb5HKDj5xaTR65Psx1pfaDfzqWKPE65
1Mweet8rkufPJfge3fekvQLActb4wW5kNc
16wrVfSkDkSNs7ZBSojJ741GMBP9Ee3Mhm
1EV3qSyz4XKoZAWvB1eVSYqHyqCNRdv9i7
13xaKyPpowEbzb18ZrNth69PTgML1i9t25
15PjLxvFvVuUASkWLTReBDf1SAnGboiE3Q
```

Comment: But how did he send the mail from MY email?
He said he used a "temp mail", but Outlook shows me like the message was sent by my email address...
Also, I use KeePass and I have different passwords for all the websites.
My email password is unique!!!

Comment: @just_a_developer he didn't. SMTP is a very old protocol and not secure in any way. SMTP spoofing is trivial. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spoofing

Comment: Wow. I didn't know SMTP had those flaws.
Can I know which was the real sender?
How can I be sure that I'm not infected by Pegasus?
Any idea where to search if someone else had the same email sent?

Comment: @just_a_developer you can write literally anything in the "from" field in an email, all they're doing is not giving you *their* actual email address.

Comment: I used to send emails as billgates@microsoft.com. I am not Bill Gates (as far as I know). The real sender was probably an infected zombie in a botnet. You cannot trace who did this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botnet & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botnet#Zombie_computer

Comment: Lots of people had the same email sent. Ill update the answer. Google phrases from the email (various versions exist) between double quotes and google the btc address.

Comment: The NSO Group was hacked and if i remember correctly the Pegasus source code was leaked. They are just using the name of a scary sounding piece of malware. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus_(spyware) & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NSO_Group & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus_Project_(investigation)

Comment: Which filter did you apply to get those blockchain addresses?
We can guess those addresses are being used for this, due the low transfer amounts and the high quantity, but we can't be sure

Comment: I simply googled the bitcoin address and I got this: https://i.imgur.com/ACZHy5h.png @just_a_developer then I copypasted the blockchain addresses and added the url in front so you can easily click on them to see the transactions.

Comment: @just_a_developer if you have been infected by Pegasus then you have bigger worries, like potentially being a reporter in a country that believes falling down elevator shafts onto a whole load of bullets is considered "suicide". They are preying on people Googling for a well known nation-state developed malware and believing that they are a sufficient threat to be monitored or attacked by national actors.

Comment: @Gantendo Now I read you previous comment.
After searching it, I get a https://www.seekoin.com/ link.
Is that a place where ppl report scammy blockchain addresses?

Comment: It is a "bitcoin searchengine", according to them.

Comment: Thank you so much guys!

Comment: @just_a_developer You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I concur with the accepted answer.  It is worthwhile adding some other things which are not really conducive to comments, so an answer is warranted -

You likely can't track down who the sender was in a way which is meaningful to an end user - however emails have a "Header" which is not normally displayed but which can be displayed by your browser on request. When asking for assistance with email it is always worthwhile providing this header information as it includes a wealth of information - including hints as to the senders location. I would expect it to originate from a hacked or free account though.

Also, as others have said, this is definitely a scam, and your devices have not been hacked.   Pegasus is government level spyware and this means (a) they won't be trying to extort money from you - they don't need your money, they want to know your whereabouts/actions and (b) They are going to fly under the radar.  Pegasus embeds itself deep in your systems and trys to stay as hidden as possible,   According to https://www.gadgetsnow.com/slideshows/pegasus-spy-tool-what-is-it-how-it-works-cost-who-can-buy-and-all-questions-answered/photolist/84534882.cms?picid=84534907 - Pegasus costs in excess of US$65k per device - so asking < $2k would be a way to loose money.

Comment: You can check how important you are here https://cdn.occrp.org/projects/project-p/#/